# I want to upload an Image and video in same time from UIImagePicker

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, xcode7

I want to upload Image and Video in same time, the bellow coding I tried but not uploading to server, I want a thumbnail of video so I will take thumbnail image from the same video and both image and video I want to upload to server

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {

               NSLog(@"Image And Video will be uploaded");

               img = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSURL *imurl=[info valueForKeyPath:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    UIImage *croppedImage = [appdel imageWithImage:img scaledToWidth:400];

             NSString *finalUniqueImageNAme1;
             NSString *finalUniqueImageNAme2;


                thumbimages = [self thumbnailImageFromURL:imurl];

                NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imurl];




                if(videoData.length)
                {

                    NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
                    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

                    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
                    NSString *localDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
                    NSString* cleanedString = [[localDateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];
                    NSString *cleanedString2 = [cleanedString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",1];

                finalUniqueImageNAme1 = [cleanedString2 stringByAppendingString:@".mp4"];

                }


                if(thumbimages != nil)
                {

                    NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
                    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

                    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
                    NSString *localDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
                    NSString* cleanedString = [[localDateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];
                    NSString *cleanedString2 = [cleanedString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",1];



                     finalUniqueImageNAme2 = [cleanedString2 stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];


                }
                 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbimages, 90);
                NSString *urlString = @"http://vygears.com/tcdc-portfolio/Abdul/chat/upload/Vupload_file.php";
                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
                [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
                NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
                [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

                NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file1\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",finalUniqueImageNAme1] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file2\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",finalUniqueImageNAme2] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];




                    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:videoData]];

                    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];



                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                [request setHTTPBody:body];

                //   NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

              // NSLog(@"Successfully uploaded");

                NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
                if(conn)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
                  //  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:true];
                    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
                }
            }
        }

        - (UIImage *)thumbnailImageFromURL:(NSURL *)videoURL {

            AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL: videoURL options:nil];
            AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
            NSError *err = NULL;
            CMTime requestedTime = CMTimeMake(12,13);     // To create thumbnail image
            CGImageRef imgRef = [generator copyCGImageAtTime:requestedTime actualTime:NULL error:&err];
            NSLog(@"err = %@, imageRef = %@", err, imgRef);
            thumbnailImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef];
            CGImageRelease(imgRef);    // MUST release explicitly to avoid memory leak
            return thumbnailImage; 
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally I have got the Code after spending some time on it

```
 img = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

NSURL *imurl=[info valueForKeyPath:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
UIImage *croppedImage = [appdel imageWithImage:img scaledToWidth:400];
NSLog(@"Image And Video will be uploaded");

        NSString *finalUniqueImageNAme1;
        NSString *finalUniqueImageNAme2;
        NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imurl];
        thumbimages = [self thumbnailImageFromURL:imurl];


        if(videoData.length)
        {

            NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
            NSString *localDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
            NSString* cleanedString = [[localDateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];
            NSString *cleanedString2 = [cleanedString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",1];

            finalUniqueImageNAme1 = [cleanedString2 stringByAppendingString:@".mp4"];

        }


        if(thumbimages != nil)
        {

            NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
            NSString *localDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
            NSString* cleanedString = [[localDateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];
            NSString *cleanedString2 = [cleanedString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",1];



            finalUniqueImageNAme2 = [cleanedString2 stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];


        }

        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbimages, 90);

        NSString *urlString = @"http://vygears.com/tcdc-portfolio/Abdul/chat/upload/Vupload_file.php";
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

        if (imageData)
        {


            //======= Image Data=======//

            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file2\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",finalUniqueImageNAme2] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            //======= Video Data=======//


            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file1\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",finalUniqueImageNAme1] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:videoData]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        }

        [request setHTTPBody:body];
        NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        if(conn)
        {
            NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
            //  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:true];
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
        }
    }
```